# How do you turn a proof of a mathematical statement into a zero-knowledge proof?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, np-complete, second-order-logic

I recently watched a video on Numberphile2 in which Avi Wigderson describes how one can prove a graph has a 3-colouring in zero-knowledge and that as 3-colouring is NP-complete, all NP statements have zero-knowledge proofs. He further emphasises that this is constructive; one can turn a proof of an NP statement into a zero-knowledge proof of that statement.

As I already understood the Cook-Levin reduction from NP problems to 3-SAT and the reduction from 3-SAT to 3-colouring, I thought I'd be able to do exactly this with a simple mathematical statement like the infinitude of the primes, but I seem to be missing some steps in the process.

I should first say that my understanding is that the statements which are in NP are precisely the statements which have a second-order formula only involving existential second-order quantification, which certainly seems to cover all the mathematical statements I can think of. For my desired example, one can express the infinitude of the primes with the following second-order formula:

$\exists f \forall x \forall y (x < f(x) \land 1 < f(x) \land (1 \nless y \lor y \nless f(x) \lor y \nmid f(x)))$

It expresses that there exists a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that the output of $f$ is prime and always produces output bigger than its input, for all natural number inputs, therefore there must be infinitely many primes. And so proving the existence of such a function $f$ constitutes a proof of the statement.

Though it's an awkward way of writing it, it does have the advantage that the predicate being quantified over is in Conjunctive Normal Form, which is what is required for the reduction from 3-SAT to 3-colourability. But I don't understand where to go from here, as the existential quantifier isn't quantifying over predicates (having Boolean outputs), the universal quantifiers are quantifying over natural numbers and the predicate involves two binary predicates on natural numbers $<$ and $|$.

How does one reduce the problem of proving a mathematical statement (second-order formula with no second-order universal quantifiers), such as the infinitude of the primes, to the problem of proving a SAT instance has a satisfying assignment? Preferably in a way that is somewhat good at minimising the size of the resultant SAT instance.

Comment: I think you're confused on a few different fronts. The quantifiers in NP range over _finite_ structures, not $\mathbb{N}$ (that's what the 'P' stands for, after all; polynomial in the size of the input). There's no reduction from an infinite $\Sigma_2$ statement to a finite one. You also have to be careful with details of language; $\mid$ is not usually taken as a primitive, even if multiplication is, so you actually have an extra layer of quantification in there. (I _think_ this is moot here, but it's the sort of thing you need to pay attention to.)]

Comment: Thanks Steven for clarifying that the NP quantifiers are over finite structures. But I'm not really sure I understand what is said in the video then. Avi describes that even Wiles's proof of Fermat's Last Theorem could be converted to a zero-knowledge proof, but clearly Fermat's Last Theorem is an infinite $\Sigma_2$ statement. On the note of the primitives, yes I realised that I should have recast $|$ as a quantified statement over the primitive of multiplication, but it didn't seem to be the crux of my misunderstanding. Though clearly it makes the formula much more complicated.

Comment: I suspect the statement you want to convert isn't "the primes are infinite", but "there is a proof that the primes are infinite with less than n steps in deductive system X", where n is an input and X is given.

Comment: Oh I see! That's the further abstraction I was missing. So you can prove in zero-knowledge that you have a proof of the infinitude of the primes by converting the statement "there is a proof of the infinitude of the primes with less than n steps in deductive system X" into a 3-colourability instance, which transforms your proof into a 3-colouring of the graph. Then you prove in zero-knowledge that the graph is 3-colourable, thereby proving that you possess the proof. Which as a side effect proves that the mathematical statement itself is true. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting the statement "the primes are infinite", you can convert the statement "there is a proof that the primes are infinite with less than n steps in deductive system X", for some X. This new statement can be more easily converted to SAT and 3-colorability.